# Class variables in shortcodes

Tags: shortcode, variables

Don't know what I'm doing wrong but, I have the following code:

```
class the_shortcode {

    //Define Class Variables

    private $var;

    public function __construct()
    {
            add_shortcode( 'the_single', array( $this, 'shortcode_2' ));

    }


    function shortcode_1() {

        $this->var = 'World';

    }

     function shortcode_2() {

         echo $this->var;

    }

}
$the_shortcode = new the_shortcode();
```

I was expecting that `shortcode_1()` would define the `$var` and that `shortcode_2()`, when called in the shortcode action, to display it resulting in "World" - but instead absolutely nothing is displayed.

On the post, I have the shortcode: [the_single]

Any thoughts of what's wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't call the method `shortcode_1()`. The setting of the var with the value Ẁorld` was not called. You must call this inside the constructor or the `shortcode_2()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the response by @bueltge :

Added extra line in the __construct() function:

```
public function __construct()
{
      $this->var = $this->shortcode_1(); //added
      add_shortcode( 'the_single', array( $this, 'shortcode_2' ));

}
```